# How to convert the below into pyspark 2.4?

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I am not able to run the below code in python 3 - spark 2.4. Please advise.

```
  AGG_rdd = AGG.select('luid', array(varFreq_list).alias('p')) \
  .rdd.map(lambda r: \
  (r.luid, map(lambda x: min(x, 9999.999), \
  np.dot(map(min, zip(r.p, cap_list_bc.value)), eqn_matrix_bc.value).tolist() 
  ) ))
```

Sorry, I don't know how to change it. I tried this:

```
  AGG_rdd = AGG.select('luid', array(varFreq_list).alias('p')) \
    .list(rdd.map(lambda r: \
    (r.luid, list(map(lambda x: min(x, 9999.999), \
    np.dot(list(map(min, zip(r.p, cap_list_bc.value))), 
    eqn_matrix_bc.value)).tolist() ) ))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add the error you are getting.

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'map' and 'float'

Comment: Error from the changed code:AttributeError                            
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'list'

Comment: Try this: AGG_rdd = AGG.select('luid', array(varFreq_list).alias('p')) \
  .rdd.map(lambda r: \
  (r.luid, [min(x, 9999.999) for x in np.dot(list(map(min, list(zip(r.p, cap_list_bc.value)))), eqn_matrix_bc.value).tolist()] ))

Comment: Have no data and defs, so see if it works, if so I will post an answer.

Comment: Post fill code pls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this pls, python 2 and python 3 differ a little. I had issues with combineByKey likewise.

```
AGG_rdd = AGG.select('luid', array(varFreq_list).alias('p')) \
 .rdd.map(lambda r: \
         (r.luid, [min(x, 9999.999) for x in np.dot(list(map(min, list(zip(r.p, cap_list_bc.value)))), eqn_matrix_bc.value).tolist()] ))
```